# Appending the same values twice when iterating through two list

Tags: loops, ansible

My ansible playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: no

  vars:
    - delete: [
          {
              "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
              "hostname": "host1",
              "value": "3fb1"
          },
          {
              "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
              "hostname": "host2",
              "value": "3fb1133"
          }
      ]

  tasks:
    - name: connect to service now cmdb table
      uri:
        url: "{{item.department_link}}"
        method: GET
        body_format: form-urlencoded
        user: "user"
        password: "password"
        timeout: 200
        validate_certs: no
      loop: "{{delete}}"
      register: test
      no_log: yes

    - debug:
        var: test.results

    - name: combine
      set_fact:
        final: "{{ final | default([]) + [ item[0] | combine({'department': item[1].json.result.name | default(None)}) ]  }}"
      when:
        - item[1].json.result.sys_id | string == item[0].value | string
      with_nested:
        - "{{delete}}"
        - "{{test.results}}"
      no_log: yes

    - debug:
        var: final
```

debug of the var: `test.results` -- truncated. -- please go to the end of the page for full output.

```json
"test.results": [
    "json": {
                "result": {
                    "name": "dept1",
                    "sys_id": "3fb1",
                }
            },
    "json": {
                "result": {
                    "name": "dept1",
                    "sys_id": "3fb1",
                }
            }]
```

debug of the var: `final`

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final": [
        {
            "department": 'dept1",
            "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
            "hostname": "host1",
            "value": "3fb1"
        },
        {
            "department": "dept1",
            "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
            "hostname": "host1",
            "value": "3fb1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see from the above, when I iterate though two lists and combine two list into one when the condition is satisfied, it for some reason put the output twice.  I have tried many different ways but no luck.

So the result I want is:
for the var: `final` - I want the ouput to only be one dict in the list like so

```json
"final": [
            {
                "department": 'dept1",
                "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
                "hostname": "host1",
                "value": "3fb1"
            }]
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Below is the full output of `test.results` and I printed its type as well. Hope this will help!!

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test.results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "cache_control": "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1",
            "changed": false,
            "connection": "close",
            "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "cookies": {
                "cook": "random input"
            },
            "cookies_string": "cookies",
            "date": "Thu, 06 Oct 2022 17:03:50 GMT",
            "elapsed": 0,
            "expires": "0",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "attributes": null,
                    "backup": null,
                    "body": null,
                    "body_format": "raw",
                    "client_cert": null,
                    "client_key": null,
                    "content": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "delimiter": null,
                    "dest": null,
                    "directory_mode": null,
                    "follow": false,
                    "follow_redirects": "safe",
                    "force": false,
                    "force_basic_auth": false,
                    "group": null,
                    "headers": {},
                    "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "mode": null,
                    "owner": null,
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "regexp": null,
                    "remote_src": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "return_content": false,
                    "selevel": null,
                    "serole": null,
                    "setype": null,
                    "seuser": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "status_code": [
                        200
                    ],
                    "timeout": 2000,
                    "unix_socket": null,
                    "unsafe_writes": false,
                    "url": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
                    "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "url_username": "user",
                    "use_proxy": true,
                    "user": "user",
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
                "hostname": "host1",
                "value": "3fb1"
            },
            "json": {
                "result": {
                    "business_unit": "",
                    "code": "",
                    "cost_center": "",
                    "dept_head": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "head_count": "",
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "FZB2",
                    "parent": "",
                    "primary_contact": "",
                    "sys_created_by": "$test",
                    "sys_created_on": "2017-01-25 05:43:39",
                    "sys_id": "3fb1",
                    "sys_mod_count": "0",
                    "sys_tags": "",
                    "sys_updated_by": "$test",
                    "sys_updated_on": "2017-01-25 05:43:39"
                }
            },
            "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
            "pragma": "no-store,no-cache",
            "redirected": false,
            "server": "ServiceNow",
           ,
            "status": 200,
            "strict_transport_security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains",
            "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
            "url": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
            "x_is_logged_in": "true",
            "x_transaction_id": "id"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "cache_control": "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1",
            "changed": false,
            "connection": "close",
            "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "cookies": {
                "cook": "random input",
                         },
            "cookies_string": "cookies",
            "date": "Thu, 06 Oct 2022 17:03:51 GMT",
            "elapsed": 0,
            "expires": "0",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "attributes": null,
                    "backup": null,
                    "body": null,
                    "body_format": "raw",
                    "client_cert": null,
                    "client_key": null,
                    "content": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "delimiter": null,
                    "dest": null,
                    "directory_mode": null,
                    "follow": false,
                    "follow_redirects": "safe",
                    "force": false,
                    "force_basic_auth": false,
                    "group": null,
                    "headers": {},
                    "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "mode": null,
                    "owner": null,
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "regexp": null,
                    "remote_src": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "return_content": false,
                    "selevel": null,
                    "serole": null,
                    "setype": null,
                    "seuser": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "status_code": [
                        200
                    ],
                    "timeout": 200,
                    "unix_socket": null,
                    "unsafe_writes": false,
                    "url": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
                    "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "url_username": "user",
                    "use_proxy": true,
                    "user": "user",
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "department_link": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
                "hostname": "host2",
                "value": "3fb1"
            },
            "json": {
                "result": {
                    "business_unit": "",
                    "code": "",
                    "cost_center": "",
                    "dept_head": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "head_count": "",
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "FZB2",
                    "parent": "",
                    "primary_contact": "",
                    "sys_created_by": "$test",
                    "sys_created_on": "2017-01-25 05:43:39",
                    "sys_id": "id",
                    "sys_mod_count": "0",
                    "sys_tags": "",
                    "sys_updated_by": "$test",
                    "sys_updated_on": "2017-01-25 05:43:39"
                }
            },
            "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
            "pragma": "no-store,no-cache",
            "redirected": false,
            "server": "ServiceNow",
            "set_cookie": "glide_user=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure, glide_user_session=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure, glide_user_route=glide.idd; Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Tue, 24-Oct-2090 20:17:58 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure, glide_session_store=3348D7BA1B561150C71B8557EC4BCB27; Max-Age=300; Expires=Thu, 06-Oct-2022 17:08:51 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure",
            "status": 200,
            "strict_transport_security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains",
            "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
            "url": "https://servicenowservices.com/api/now/table/da/3fb1",
            "x_is_logged_in": "true",
            "x_transaction_id": "123"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test.results | type_debug": "list"
}
```

Comment: Regarding "_I have tried many different ways but no luck._", a description of what was tried and what was the result would be helpful. Since you are already using `combine` you may take advantage from [Selecting from sets or lists (set theory)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory).

Comment: @U880D ```different ways include:``` converting the list to the dictionary or json and trying to combine it. I will add those information in future questions, thank you for your suggestion. also, I did find a workaround for this - please see my comment below to Prasad Pati.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue because test.results varialbe have duplicate json blocks.

I have removed them using map and unique functions

Please try this modified task

```
- name: combine
      set_fact:
        final: "{{ final | default([]) + [ item[0] | combine({'department': item[1].result.name | default(None)}) ]  }}"
      when:
        - item[1].result.sys_id | string == item[0].value | string
      with_nested:
        - "{{delete}}"
        - "{{test.results | map(attribute='json') | unique }}"
      no_log: yes
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work, and the got the error `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{test.results | map(attribute='json') | unique}}): unhashable type: 'dict'"}` but you gave me an idea of using unique, and used that like so ***- debug: var: final | unique*** and now its only printing unique ones.   Thank you.

Comment: I also added the full output of test.results to see if that makes any difference on your tests.